# How to design around the limitation that templated member functions can't be virtual

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

I'm running into a design issue where (in C++) I'd like a templated member function (of a non-template class) to be virtual and am wondering if there is a good, elegant way around the issue.

The scenario goes, I have *machines* that *process* generic *items*.  I use an abstract base class for *machines* with a virtual *process(Item)* function so that each machine can define their own unique processing method.  The problem is that the items are also "generic" in that they expose certain interfaces for how they can be processed.  For reasons (mainly for performance...no vtable overhead), I'd like to use compile-time polymorphism for these items.  So that now each machine would have an interface like:

```
class Machine
{ public:
    template <typename T>
    virtual void process(T& item) = 0; 
};
```

However this is impossible in C++ as templated member functions cannot be virtual.  certainly I can make the machine class templated on the Item type T but this adds more headaches for me in the larger design scheme and really no other part of the Machine class depends on Item...it's only an argument to the process() function.

Is there a better way around this or any suggestions for how to provide this kind of generic family of machines that process a family of generic items (where the items use compile-time polymorphism).  Am I off the deep end in terms of my design.

Appreciate any suggestions

Comment: So a specific machine can process items of any type? And are item types intrinsically unrelated, or could you make an `Item` superclass?

Comment: Do you need to access a concrete machine via a pointer to the abstract `Machine` class? If not (if you can access it via the concrete class), [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) is the way to go (keyword: "static polymorphism").

Comment: You have two choices here: CRTP and double dispatch. Here you say you don't want double dispatch, but this may be premature optimization (think about it).

Comment: Yes any specific machine can process any item using the basic interfaces that Items *should* provide.  And yes, I do need to access (or that is my intention) a concrete machine(s) from an abstract pointer (think of an assembly line that passes an item through a sequence of machines that each process the item doing their portion of work on that item).

Comment: In this case, DD is the way to go, as in DeadMG's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, double dispatch is used.

```
class Machine;
class Item {
public:
    virtual void bounce(Machine& mach);
};
class Machine {
public:
    template<typename T> void process(T& t);
    virtual void process(Item& i) {
        return i.bounce(*this);
    }
};
template<typename T> class CRTPItem {
public:
    virtual void bounce(Machine& mach) {
        return mach.process(*(T*)this);
    }
};
class ConcreteItem : public CRTPItem<ConcreteItem> {
public:
    // blah blah
};
```

In this case, you don't need virtual overhead for the whole ConcreteItem interface, and they don't need anything in common, just that one `bounce` function which is built for you automatically by inheriting from `CRTPItem`. This is only two vtable calls as opposed to the one you had originally, as opposed to needing a vtable call for all of Item's functions, and the interface can still retain all strong-typing that it would have if you could create virtual templates.

Comment: Isn't `CRTPItem<>` meant to derive from `Item`?

Comment: Should CTRPItem derive from Item and how would a DerivedMachine's process get called? (i.e. what would a DerivedMachine look like)?

Comment: @DeadMG Should CTRPItem derive from Item and how would a DerivedMachine's process get called? (i.e. what would a DerivedMachine look like)?