# Yet another use-case of template virtual function

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions

I'm trying to implement something similar to the Visitor pattern.

The following isn't the full code of course, so you might wonder about the motivation of the code, but you can get the structure which is relevant for the question.

I have the following:

```
class base
{
public:
    GetValue(int &val);
    GetValue(char &val);
    GetValue(vector<double> &val);

    virtual accept(baseVisitor* p){};

};

template <typename T>
Derived1 : public Base
{

public:
    GetValue(T &val);
    virtual accept(baseVisitor* p)
    {
        p->visitDerived1();
    }

private:
    T m_val;
};

Derived2 : public Base
{
    GetValue(int &val);
    virtual accept(baseVisitor* p)
    {       
        p->visitDerived2();
    }
private:
    int m_val;
};


class baseVisitor
{
    virtual visitDerived1(Base* p);
    virtual visitDerived2(Base* p);
}

class DerivedVisitor
{
    virtual visitDerived1(Base* p)
    {
        //Do something with m_val
    }

    virtual visitDerived2(Base* p)
    {
        //Do something with m_val
    }
}
```

The implementation for `visitDerived2` is very simple. I need to call `GetValue` with an int argument and then do something on it. I ould do the same with `visitDerived1` if virtual template function were allowed, then I would have done the following:

```
template <typename T>
virtual visitDerived1(Base* p)
{
        T val ;
        GetValue(val);
        //Do something with m_val
}
```

But template virtual function doesn't compile.

I saw a few workarounds for this problem in general but none seemed suited for my situation.

What workaround do you suggest for that?

Comment: You haven't told us what the compiler error is, or on which line of code you are getting the compiler error.

Comment: If you think long and hard about virtual functions and how they're typically implemented (think v-tables), you'll understand how/why they don't place nice with templates and thus disallowed by the standard. You'd have an unknown number of entries in the v-table until you've instantiated every single possible invocation of the template. Generally not a solvable problem.

Comment: You'll have to put your code changes back in.  I fixed all of your spelling errors.

Comment: Did you mean `p->GetValue(val)`?

Comment: Suppose `visitDerived1` *could* be a template. How would it know which of the infinite derived1 types was actually at hand?

Comment: @Mooing, Because I want to have different type of visitors, each of which does a different work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, The compiler complains when I try to define a template virtual function, for the reason Nathan Ernst explained.

Comment: @MarkB, you got me beat! Still, I need a way here :)

Comment: Sounds like you need to try something else that doesn't involve defining a template virtual function.  Have you seen this yet? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15592424